# Combine and Observable Macro iOS 17

Tags: swift, observable, combine

I have read the [migration guide](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/migrating-from-the-observable-object-protocol-to-the-observable-macro) and am still stuck on this one. In the spirit of the migration guide ...

OLD

```swift
class MyClass: ObservableObject {
    @Published var myVariable: String = "Need to know"
    
    var subscriptions: Set<AnyCancellable> = []
    
    init() {
        $myVariable.sink { updated_variable in
            //Need to operate
        }.store(in: &subscriptions)
    }
    
}
```

NEW

```swift
@Observable class MyClass {
    var myVariable: String = "Need to know"
    
    var subscriptions: Set<AnyCancellable> = []
    
    init() {
        /*
         Error!
         Cannot find '$myVariable' in scope
         */
        $myVariable.sink { updated_variable in
            //Need to operate
        }.store(in: &subscriptions)
    }
    
}
```

I really liked subscribing to and for that matter assigning to @Published variables with combine. Can I still do this in any way?

Answer (score 2):

No, I don't think this is possible anymore because the `@Observable` macro isn't using Combine